# Does the Markov property of a Random Variable allow us to say that the expected value of the future is independent of the past, given the present?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, markov-process

Given some probability space, say $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, and the fact that $\mathcal{X}$ is $\mathbb{F}$-adapted, and $\mathcal{X}$ is Markov, then I know the following is true:

$\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{X_t} \in A | \mathcal{F}_s) = \mathbb{P}(X_t \in A | \mathcal{X}_s)$

...which follows directly from the fact that $\mathcal{X}_t - \mathcal{X}_s \mathrel{\unicode{x2AEB}} \mathcal{X}_s \, \forall s \le t$

But is it also true to say these two claims:

1)   $\mathcal{X}_t \mathrel{\unicode{x2AEB}} \mathcal{F}_s |  \mathcal{X}_s \, \forall s \le t$

2)   $\mathbb{E}\mathcal{X}_t \mathrel{\unicode{x2AEB}} \mathcal{F}_s | \mathcal{X}_s \, \forall s \le t$

It seems to be true intuitively but I cannot derive mathematically.

Comment: Don't think so. Let's say I model diffusion of a particle in a 1D space by  a chain of states indicating position of the particle. The transition may be A <-> B <-> C <-> D <-> E <-> F, where the double arrows indicate possible transition with probability of 10%. The present position has less effect on the (expected) position 10 steps later than on the  (expected) position 1 step later. The effect of the present position may be negligible for the positions 10000 steps later. I don't know measure theory, but I think Markov property doesn't mean the past can't affect the future.

Comment: What does F-adapted mean?

Comment: Here is a better explanation for F-adapted than I could probably give myself: https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/11/08/filtrations-and-adapted-processes/

Comment: "[...] which follows directly from the fact that $\mathcal{X}_t-\mathcal{X}_s \mathrel{\unicode{x2AEB}} \mathcal{X}_s$" That's in general not true.... Markov processes do not need to have independent increments.

Comment: Ah.  I see.  But if a process *does* have independent increments, then the following two things are true:  1)  it is Markov, and 2) $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{X_t} \in A | \mathcal{F}_s) = \mathbb{P}(X_t \in A | \mathcal{X}_s) \forall s \le t$.  But the converse is not necessarily true for either of those.

Comment: @saz is that ^ true?

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Comment: But 2) in my original question seems to be a false claim.

Comment: Final question - the $X_s$ that I said in the independent increments should actually be $\mathcal{F}_s$ it seems to me.  Is that right?